# Converting BAM files to FASTQ using Google Colab

Tags: r, google-colaboratory, bioinformatics, fastq, bam

I am trying to convert BAM files from Ion Amplicon sequencing to FASTQ files. I am using Google Collaboratory. I will be using the FASTQ files in R for the pipeline DADA2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you using Google colab for this? Are you uploading BAM files? Are they already available within Google colab. I would advise against using colab for processing of raw sequencing data. For example, when installed locally, the ever useful `bedtools` has a utility to convert BAM to FASTQ files.

Comment: In R maybe this will help: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/119522/

Comment: I will have to upload the BAM files from my computer, I'm not certain how to use Google Colab. It's just the only coding platform I've been exposed to.

Comment: @Nicole_B In that case I *really* advise *against* using Google colab. File sizes of BAM and FASTQ files can become fairly large, which would create a lot of upload/download traffic. Better to install one of the standard tools (like `bedtools`, `samtools` etc.) and work on those file locally from the command line (no coding necessary). Chances are that you'll be needing some of those standard tools in your downstream bioinformatics work again.